# Custom Facebook Android App

Tags: android, facebook

I have done logging through Faceboo sdk in android and it was successful. Now, What I want is to create a custom login screen and on the press of submit it should send the request directly to facebook server like the original facebook app. I don't want to redirect to facebook's generated login screen. You can say it is like developing our own facebook app. The problem is I'm not getting any API to do this. Does any one knows how to do it..?

Comment: Check out the [Facebook Developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/), here is some documentation on the Facebook SDK 3.0, note that it is in Beta

Answer (score 5):

Having the user type in their username/password on your own custom login screen is not supported by Facebook. You need to use SSO or the dialog option.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I know is to implement sign-in feature at server side, refer these links for more details: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/

I was in similar situation and I'm going to do it. Please let me know if you succeed by this or if you have other solution.